# jqgrid search issue

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid which works quite well,except for the search functionality.

My grid code :

```
    $("#packagesListTable").jqGrid('GridUnload');

    $("#packagesListTable").jqGrid({

        pager : "#packagesListTablePager",
        width:$("#contentTD").width()-25,
        height : $("#contentTD").height()-100,
        colNames:['Package Description','Maintain Page'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'packageDescription',index:'packageDescription',search:true, stype:'text',sortable:true, width:190},
            {name:'packageDescription',index:'packageDescription',sortable:true, width:80,formatter:buttonColumnFormatPackage}
        ],

        url:allPackageDevs,
        datatype: "json",

        pgbuttons: false,     // disable page control like next, back button
        pgtext: null,         // disable pager text like 'Page 0 of 10'
        viewrecords: false ,  

        jsonReader : {
             root: 'content.packages',
             repeatitems: false,
             id:'packageId'
        },
        rowNum:-1,

        loadComplete: function () {
            $("#packagesListTable").setGridParam({datatype:'local'});
        },

        loadonce: true, // to enable sorting on client side
        sortable: true, //to enable sorting

        caption: "&nbsp;Packages"
        }
    );



    $("#packagesListTable").jqGrid('navGrid', '#packagesListTablePager',
     { add: true, addtitle: 'Add record',
       edit: true, edittitle: 'Edit record',
       del: true, deltitle: 'Delete record',
       delfunc:removePackageRow,
       addfunc:addNewPackageItem,
       editfunc:editPackageItem
     },{},{},{},{},{});
```

my search results :

[image]

[image]

So when I search for something specific I can't find it.Another issue is when I search for a item with 'start with' and it contains a space I only get one result.

Many thanks

V